# Is is possible to change HTTP status in MessageBodyWriter?

Tags: java, jersey, http-status

How can I change HTTP status in MessageBodyWriter in Jersey?
I know I can change header and the body response message via httpHeaders and entityStream in writeTo method, but I dont know how to change the HTTP status.

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageBodyWriterJSON implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object t, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
        WebApplicationException {
        // ...???
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the http status by throwing a WebApplicationException.

```
Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
throw new WebApplicationException(response);
```

Comment: While this might technically cover all Response.Status types, it doesn't really feel appropriate to throw an exception to choose between a 200 OK vs. a 204 No Content.

Comment: we are using this for sending a not modified response